# Check for '04' at the start of a number

Tags: php

I need away to tell if a $_POST[phone] is starting with 04 if it is I want run a query

In javascript I know how to do this but for some reason on Ubuntu 8 (Yes I know its old) and Firefox the agents are able to still post 04 number in mobile field after testing my javascript query over and over again - I thought instead

Comment: What did you try? Show your code.

Comment: Sorry, this needs to be a little more specific. @sectus is right, please show some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a substr like this:

```
if (substr($_POST['phone'], 0, 2) == '04') {
    // ... do some code here
}
```

If you want to match multiple strings at the same time you could do this (it's faster than doing an `in_array()`):

```
$prefixes    = array('02'=>true, '03'=>true, '07'=>true, '08'=>true);
$inputPrefix = substr($_POST['phone'], 0, 2);

if (isset($prefixes[$inputPrefix])) {
    // ... do some code here
}
```

Comment: will this work if i want to make sure the number start with the either 03,02,07,08 I know I could do != '03' || !=02 etc

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment if you want to make sure it is only `03`, `02`, `07` or `08` you can do the following:

```
$telephonePrefix = substr($_POST['phone'], 0, 2);
$knowPrefixes = array('03','02','07','08');

if (in_array($telephonePrefix , $knowPrefixes)) {
    // ... do some code here
}
```